# Vertical dividers on horizontal UL menu

Tags: html, css, markup

I'm trying to create a horizontal navigation bar (no dropdown, just a horizontal list), but I'm having trouble finding the best way to add vertical dividers between the menu items.

The actual HTML is as follows:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

The current CSS is as follows:

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Between each menu item I want a small image as a vertical divider, except that I don't want a divider shown before the first item and I don't want a divider shown after the second item.

The end result should look something like this:

> Item 1  |  Item 2  |  Item 3  | Item 4  | Item 5

Just replacing the pipe with an actual image.

I've tried different ways - I've tried setting the `list-style-image` property, but the image didn't show up. I've also tried setting the divider as a background which actually more or less worked except that it made the first item have a divider in front of it.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Quite and simple without any "having to specify the first element". CSS is more powerful than most think (e.g. the `first-child:before` is great!). But this is by far the cleanest and most proper way to do this, at least in my opinion it is.

```css
#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

#navigation li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: " | ";
}
```

Now just use a simple unordered list in HTML and it'll populate it for you. HTML should look like this:

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- navigation -->
```

The result will be just like this:

> HOME | ABOUT US | SUPPORT

Now you can indefinitely expand and never have to worry about order, changing links, or your first entry. It's all automated and works great!

Comment: You sir are awesome.  This method worked for me very well.  Since it is all done in CSS, it will be very simple if I need to make changes.

Comment: Have you considered `:not(:first-child):before`

Comment: Note that the final two rules can be consolidated into one: `#navigation li + li:before { content: " | "; }`

Answer (score 31):

try this one, seeker:

```
li+li { border-left: 1px solid #000000 }
```

this will affect only adjecent li elements

found [here](http://www.jackreichert.com/2011/07/31/how-to-add-a-divider-between-menu-items-in-css-using-only-one-selector/)

Comment: This is just awesome!

Answer (score 12):

This can also be done via CSS:pseudo-classes. Support isn't quite as wide and the answer above gives you the same result, but it's pure CSS-y =)

```
.ULHMenu li { border-left: solid 2px black; }
.ULHMenu li:first-child { border: 0px; }
```

OR:

```
.ULHMenu li { border-right: solid 2px black; }
.ULHMenu li:last-child { border: 0px; }
```

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html
Or: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 2):

I think your best shot is a `border-left` property that is assigned to each one of the `li`s except the first one (You would have to give the first one a class named `first` and explicitly remove the border for that).

Even if you are generating the `<li>` programmatically, assigning a `first` class should be easy.

Comment: It's even safe to rely on [CSS 2.1 Selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) and use `ul > li:first-child` to target that first element without adding any extra markup.

Comment: Just also pointing out that he asked for an image divider rather than a side-border, but essentially the same idea (giving a background-image to the `<li>`)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be to just add `#navigation ul li~li { border-left: 1px solid #857D7A; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
.last { border-right: none

.last { border-right: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

NB I'm using  <strike>BEM/OCSS</strike> SCSS Syntax

```
#navigation{
  li{
     &:after{
        content: '|'; // use content for box-sizing
        text-indent: -999999px; // Hide the content
        display: block;
        float: right; // Position
        width: 1px;
        height: 100%; // The 100% of parent (li)
        background: black; // The color
        margin: {
          left: 5px;
          right: 5px;
        }
      }

      &:last-child{

        &:after{
          content: none;
        }

      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I do it as Pekka says. Put an inline style on each `<li>`:

```
style="border-right: solid 1px #555; border-left: solid 1px #111;"
```

Take off first and last as appropriate.