# Dividers on Horizontal Nav list

Tags: html, css, list, divider

My task is to input some horizontal bars between links on a simple, unsorted nav list for my company's website.

I've tried each method listed on [Vertical dividers on horizontal UL menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936661/vertical-dividers-on-horizontal-ul-menu) , to no avail. One of the links in that thread led me to http://www.jackreichert.com/2011/07/31/how-to-add-a-divider-between-menu-items-in-css-using-only-one-selector/ , which worked!...kind of.

http://s21.postimg.org/nno183jl3/problems.jpg

That's what I'm getting right now: the dividers have moved off to the left hand side of the nav list. At this point, I'm a little stumped, so I was hoping you guys could help me out.

Here's the HTML. "cart_count.tpl" is the shopping cart stuff on the right.

```
<div style=float:right id="topbar">
 <nav>
  <div id="thisisthecartfunction" style=float:right>
   {include file="cart_count.tpl"}</div>
  <ul style=float:right>
   <li><a href="/member">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="/member_wishlist">Wish List</a></li>
   <li><a href="/tracking">Order Status</a></li>
   <li><a href="/category/customer-service">Customer Service</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </nav>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS. I know it's a bit long and cluttered.

```
#container > header > #topbar { width: 100%; background: #f8f8f8; margin: 0 auto;}
#container > header > #topbar > nav { width: 980px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto;}
#container > header > #topbar > nav > div > #cartitems {vertical-align: bottom; margin: 3px 0px 10px 10px; }
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;}
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li+li { border-left: 1px solid #000000 }
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li > a {display: inline; float: right; background: #f8f8f8; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: bottom; margin: 5px 0px 10px 10px; }
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li > a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all change `style=float:right` to `style="float:right;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good direction would be to use a separate list item as a placeholder for each divider like so:

```
#topbar { width: 100%; background: #f8f8f8; margin: 0 auto;}
#topbar > nav { width: 980px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px auto;}
#topbar > nav > ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;float:left;}
#topbar > nav > ul > li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;}
#topbar > nav > ul > li > a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

<div id="topbar">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/member">My Account</a></li>
   <li class="divider">|</li>
   <li><a href="/member_wishlist">Wish List</a></li>
   <li class="divider">|</li>
   <li><a href="/tracking">Order Status</a></li>
    <li class="divider">|</li>
   <li><a href="/category/customer-service">Customer Service</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </nav>
</div>
```

That way you can clean up your current CSS and have granular control over the divider, be it an image or text. Also notice that I removed the float from `<div id="topBar">` and `<ul>`. You only need a float in your CSS for the `<ul>`. I also removed the `#container > header >` from your CSS as it is superfluous CSS.  See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QhCeH/

Comment: This method really did work the best. After a little bit of editing and clean up, the little lines are perfectly spaced and looking good. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to accomplish this and also in my opinion the easiest, is setting border-right to your `<li>` elements. A made a simple, choppy **[JSfiddle as an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6j39j/)**

As you can see, it's nothing beautiful but you get the idea. This also avoids using the HTML `<nav>` element, which in my opinion is generally useless and I have found you can achieve much more precision in design using unordered lists. In this case, you could even add a class `first` so that you can have a border at the beginning of the first element as well.

Example:

```
.first {
    border-left: 1px solid #hexhex
    height: set the height;
```

Comment: I can't say I agree with your comment regarding the `nav` element. Using your fiddle as an example you would be more semanticaly correct to use `<nav>` instead of `<div id="nav">`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/aeyzS/1/)?

```
#thisisthecartfunction {
    width: 200px
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

li:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

li:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

<div style="float:right" id="topbar">
 <nav>
  <ul style="float:right">
   <li><a href="/member">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="/member_wishlist">Wish List</a></li>
   <li><a href="/tracking">Order Status</a></li>
   <li><a href="/category/customer-service">Customer Service</a></li>
  </ul> 
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On `#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li > a` added `border-right: 1px solid #333; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;`

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/WysRK/)

```
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li > a { display: inline; float: right; border-right: 1px solid #333; background: #f8f8f8; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0 10px 0 10px; margin: 5px 0px 10px 0; }

#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li:last-child a { border-left: 1px solid #333; }
```

and because your `<ul>` has `float: right;` I added `border-left: 1px solid #333;` to the last child which is first item in this case.

or maybe you want full height separators

```
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li {display: block; float: right; border-right: 1px solid #333; list-style: none;}
#container > header > #topbar > nav > ul > li:last-child { border-left: 1px solid #333; }
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/yzmBa/)